# How to get 2D-Array of boxplots without the diagonal with R (python also accepted)?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

I want to do comparison between different factors with box plots. One factor doesn't compare with it self. So I need a matrix of `boxplots`  (wich I could get using `ggplot`) but without the diagonal. The results is like this but with boxplots. I'm not restricted to `R`. I may use `python` if suited.

```
pairs(iris[,1:4])
```

Output:

[image]

Thanks

[EDIT]: here is the data http://pastebin.com/ujvnhtNE the labeln-labeln is not needed and I can easily get rid of it. I'd like a box-plot to denote a label vs. another with two shots in it

Comment: What do you mean by `diagonal`?  The one with the column names?

Comment: @Dawny33 exactly

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A boxplot only looks at one variable, so how can you have a boxplot of anything *except* the "diagonal"?

Comment: My data are the result of a comparison. I can explain their semantics but I don't think it's relevant. Some research article used this. Here is an example (page 15): www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/sop/publicationListFiles/zdt2000a.pdf

Comment: So what do the rows and columns of your data look like? Give us a sample, and tell us which columns are the factors you want paired off and which constitute factors to remain in the boxplots in each individual "plotlet"?

Comment: @Spacedman please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The [`GGally`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=GGally) package, which is an extension of `ggplot2`, might be what you need. Here are the explanations for the code below.

- `upper = "blank"` removes the plots on the upper right
- `lower = list(combo = "box", continuous = "blank")` plots a boxplot for ever pair of variables where one is categorical and the other is continuous, but does not print the plot when both variables are categorical. (Try removing `continous = "blank"` to see what happens.)
- `diag = NULL` removes the plots in the diagonals.

You may tailor this for your particular use.

```
library(GGally)
mtcars[1:4] %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  ggpairs(upper = "blank",
          lower = list(combo = "box", continuous = "blank"),
          diag = NULL
          # remove the column labels, but why would you do that?
          # columnLabels = NULL)
```

[image]